# How To Add Perfect Apostrophe And Quotation Mark In WordPress Posts?

Tags: posts, shortcode, code, css

I have a blog at [www.exeideas.com](http://www.exeideas.com/) where I am sharing codes snippet too. I am new to WordPress and migrated from Blogger. So now my all codes shared in posts stop working. When I check my codes then found that all was fin but just Apostrophe, Quotation and, Dash are changes that is causing to stop my codes. I am sharing below what I am getting and what I want.

1. I am getting `’` and want `'`.
2. I am getting `”` and want `"`.
3. I am getting `‘` and want `'`.
4. I am getting `–` and want `-`.

Now tell me what to do to fix this out. My code box CSS is given below.

`#execodediv0 {width:99%;max-height:300px;border:3px solid black;overflow:auto;font: 12px Arial!important;word-wrap:break-word;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter responsible for adding these characters is [wptexturize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize), you can remove it using [remove_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter).

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wptexturize' );
```

Comment: As I said that I am new to WordPress so can you share the whole code that I have to add in template `function.php`...

Comment: I added it directly in `function.php` and its working. Thanks for solving...